# TeX Live Manager Update setup on Linux

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu

The lastest Ubuntu repository TeXLive is outdated. But it's already installed. According to its documentation it can updated via TeXLive Manager.

> If I run
>
> sudo /usr/bin/tlmgr --gui with perl-tk installed I get an error:
>
> "This may take some time, please be patient ...
>   cannot setup TLPDB in /home/dmnq/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.
>   Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 4445."
>
> I have the ubuntu repository texlive 2013. *What am I doing wrong?*

BTW: I normally prefer using the TUG iso or the repository to install. This I found useful https://milindpadalkar.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/installing-texlive-2010-in-ubuntu-10-04-10-10-and-11-04/ but not sure if it's still valid.

Comment: Yes; the Ubuntu provided `tlmgr` is in `/usr/bin` so you're asking for a different program, which knows the environment and will do everything in `/usr/local/texlive/2014`, not in the system provided TeX Live tree.

Comment: so sudo /usr/bin/tlmgr --gui is the correct command? yes?

Comment: Sorry: it is ***not*** correct; you were mentioning `/opt/texbin/tlmgr` which is the right command (if you have created the symbolic link); `/usr/bin/tlmgr` will run the distribution provided `tlmgr`, which will not act on the manually installed TeX Live

Comment: I have the texlive from the ubuntu package manager on this computer. usr/bin/ version gives the error above. /opt/texbin/ gives command not found. So you were right the first time ... but an error results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have both a GNU/Linux distribution provided TeX Live and a manually installed one, you'll have two different `tlmgr`.

The one in `/usr/bin` will *not* update packages, but just change configuration parameters.

The one in `/usr/local/texlive/<YEAR>/bin/<ARCH>`, instead, will do updates to the manually installed TeX Live. Here `<YEAR>` stands for the version you have, probably `2014`, while `<ARCH>` is the standard symbolic name for the processor, say `x86_64-linux` or `i386-linux`.

The correct call, if your data is as above, is

```
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr --gui
```

When doing a manual installation of TeX Live, I recommend doing

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux /opt/texbin
```

so you just need to add to your PATH the simpler `/opt/texbin` and have another benefit: when TeX Live 2015 is released and you install it, you just have to do

```
sudo rm /opt/texbin
sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux /opt/texbin
```

and do *no* other change to your setup, because your PATH variable will already point to the correct location. If you create this symbolic link, then

```
sudo /opt/texbin/tlmgr --gui
```

will become the correct call.

See [this article on TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100gregorio.pdf) which explains the installation procedure I recommend and that's still valid provided you just change the year from 2010 to the current release year.